# Powershell Module: Enable/Get Server-Manager Module Windows 7

Tags: powershell, module, servermanager

I've installed Win Remote Mgmt tools on my Windows 7 Enterprise. I would like to remote manage my servers and to run script which would need the SEVERMANAGER MODULE. After installing the Remote Mgmt tools and activating them as a feature, I started Powershell and tried to import the Module by tipping: Import-Module ServerManager ==> Ended with an error.

Then I wanted to check what modules are active nad tippe: get-Module -List * and there were the AD, Bitlocker modules and so on.

So whats the Problem with the SERVERMANAGER MODULE?

Can some one give me a hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServerManager is a server module, it doesn't exist on client machines. One thing you can do is use create a new PowerShell Remoting session agaist the target server, load the ServerManager and run its commands using remoting commands.

Answer (score 1):

The ServerManager module does not exist on Windows client machines, this is/was true. However, now you can get the ServerManager  module for Windows 8.1 (I am uncertain if it exists for anything prior unfortunately - the docs seem to suggest not).

You cannot run ServerManager cmdlets against the client machines - but you can run them against Windows Server 2012 R2 machines from the client machines.

[At time of writing, the link is here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296)

If you search on MSDN/Bing/Google for 'Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8.1' (or some synonym-esque version of that) you will find the module installer you are looking for.